# How to start the windows application when we starts the computer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, registry

How to start the windows application when we starts the computer. In my application I want to update the current date & time in registry.

Comment: ehh? Update current date & time in registry? Also theres a difference between boot time and when a user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add it to the "startup" folder which you can find the Windows button -> All programs.
It might be named differently if you have a localized Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Run" key in the registry.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314866

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Startup* folder, thats easy to handle by your users if they do not want it anymore.

Then there ist the *Run* key in the registry, see Andrew' answer.

Also you might set up a windows service which does things not interactivly and also when no user is logged in. This service can do a single thing, start up automatic und terminate after finishing its work (it does not need to loop like most services).

Answer (score 0):

You can use two easy ways to do this.

Add to Start up folder

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)
```

Add registry entry

```
RegistryKey myKey= Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);    
myKey.SetValue("Your Application Name", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() + "\);
```